# Filtering a WPF Datagrid with a DataTable as its Itemssource is throwing exception

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, datatable, datagrid

I have a datagrid whose itemssource I'm setting as a datatable's "DefaultView" which is a dataview.

I have a textbox on the page for filtering. As I type text into the textbox, I'm updating the datagrid's "Filter", but it's throwing a NotSupportedException "Specified method is not supported." I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code where I create the DataTable:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
        templates[0].FieldList[0].Items.Sort();

        foreach (var tag in templates[0].FieldList[0].Items)
        {
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn() { ColumnName = tag.Name };
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
        }

        foreach (var temp in templates)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

            foreach (var tag in temp.FieldList[0].Items)
            {
                if (dt.Columns.Contains(tag.Name))
                    row[tag.Name] = tag.TagValue;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dt;
```

Then I simply set the grid's Itemssource property to that datatable's "DefaultView"

Here's where I set the filter of the datagrid:

```
 private void SearchText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LookUpDataGrid.Items.Filter = TextFilter;
    }
```

Then here's the "TextFilter" method:

```
private bool TextFilter(object o)
    {
        if (o.GetType().Equals(typeof(ExpandoObject)))
        {
            var row = o as IDictionary<string, object>;
            foreach (var v in row.Values)
            {
                if (v.ToString().ToLower().Contains(SearchText.Text.ToLower()))
                    return true;
            }
        }

        string[] propertyNames = o.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name == "String").Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
        return propertyNames.Any(p => ((string)o.GetType().GetProperty(p).GetValue(o, null)).ToLower().Contains(SearchText.Text.ToLower()));
    }
```

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) says this *Use the CanFilter property to test whether the current implementation supports filtering before assigning this property with a non-null value.* suggesting that not everything that you can bind to is filterable.

Comment: I just added that prior to setting the filter on the textchanged and you're correct. It's "False".

So it looks like I should probably attempt to generate a dynamic object based on the items and the complex property of "FieldList", then bind to that collection rather than creating a datatable.

Comment: you might want to look at collectionviewsource

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filer a DataTable using the Filter property of the `ICollectionView` interface. Instead you should use the RowFilter property of the DataView, e.g.:

```
DataView dv = LookUpDataGrid.ItemsSource as DataView;
if(dv != null)
{
    dv.RowFilter = "n = 1"; //where n is a column name of the DataTable
}
```

Also the type of an item in a DataView is never an `ExpandoObject`. It's always a `DataRowView` so the implementation of your TextFilter method wouldn't work anyway.

You should probably consider setting the ItemsSource to something else than a DataView, for example an `IEnumerable<ExpandoObject>`.